# Turn a textfield in javafx to be encrypted

Tags: java, javafx

I have create a sign up scene in my javafx application. The sign up scene contains several textfields like name, username and password. I am wandering how can I set the textfield of the password to be encrypted in order no one can see the pass. My code is the following:

```
class MySignUpTextField extends TextField {
    public MySignUpTextField() {
        setPrefWidth(400.0);
        setPrefHeight(60.0);
        setStyle("-fx-font: 30 cornerstone; -fx-text-fill: black; -fx-base: #17499F;");
}}

passSignupSLabel = new MySignUpLabel("Password:");
SsignupButtonPane.add(passSignupSLabel , 1, 2);

passSignupSTextField = new MySignUpTextField();
SsignupButtonPane.add(passSignupSTextField , 2, 2);
```

How can I turn the the passSignupSTextField to be encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider using a `PasswordField` instead of a `TextField`?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PasswordField.html

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it depends on what you mean by 'encrypted'. If you mean 'encrypted' as in scrambling the input before you send information to a database or server, then your question is way too broad. If you want to mask the input of the TextField, there is a really easy solution. Create a new class, MySignUpPasswordField, and make that class extends PasswordField instead of TextField. PasswordField already masks the input for you, so you don't have to do it manually. 
Here is where you can learn more about PasswordFields, http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/password-field.htm

Answer (score 2):

Use [PasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PasswordField.html) instead of `TextField`, which is subclass of `TextField` and masks entered characters.